# Python - Input a str. and convert it to a number. (print calculation)

Tags: python-3.x, input

How do I input a letter (a , b or c) and then print out a result as a int.(5 * 1) and  not a str? (5 * a).

```
number = int(input("Input a number: "))
letter = input("Input a latter: ")

a = 1
b = 5
c = 3

print(number * letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a dictionary here as follows:

For your code:

```
number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
letter = input('Enter a letter: ')
dict = {'a':1,'b':5,'c':3}
print( number * dict[letter.lower()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
number = int(input('Input a number: '))
letter = input('Input a letter: ')

a = 1
b = 5
c = 3

letter = letter.lower()
if letter in 'abc':
    idx = 'abc'.index(letter)
    letter = [a, b, c][idx]

print(number * letter)
```

For a more flexible way, you can do this:

```
number = int(input('Input a number: '))
letter = input('Input a letter: ')

a = 1
b = 5
c = 3
d = 4

letter = letter.lower()

# locals() returns a dict of all variables in the current scope.
v = locals().get(letter)
if v is None:
    print('"%s" is not an expected choice!' % letter)
else:
    print(number * v)
```

Comment: You are a GOD! thank you very much! solved my problem.

Comment: You are welcome! And if you like please accept this to be the answer.